# python list inquiry

Tags: python, list

My list looks like this:

```
[',100,"","Rock outcrop","Miscellaneous area"']
```

I want to add in double quotes before the 100.

so that it looks like this:

```
['"",100,"","Rock outcrop","Miscellaneous area"']
```

I tried the insert function, but that only adds something to my list before the start of my list. When I did insert, it looked like this

```
['', ',100,"","Rock outcrop","Miscellaneous area"']
```

Comment: It looks like you're starting with a list, but that list contains a *single* string that contains commas and quotes. Is that really what you want? Or do you want a list with four items, an integer and three strings?

Answer (score 1):

What you've got is a single string, containing

```
,100,"","Rock outcrop","Miscellaneous area"
```

inside a list. If what you want is to add `""` to the beginning of that string, then you can do that by doing

```
mylist[0] = '""' + mylist[0]
```

But I assume that you probably want an actual sequence of strings, in which case you want

```
import ast
mylist = ast.literal_eval('""' + mylist[0])
#mylist is now ('', 100, '', 'Rock outcrop', 'Miscellaneous area')
```

[`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) interprets a string as a Python literal, in this case a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually have is a list of one string. So just pull out the string.

```
s = l[0]
s = '""' + s
```

But... that's an odd use of a list and string. You might want to use a different structure.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the list

```
lst = [',100,"","Rock outcrop","Miscellaneous area"']
```

So what you can do is get the first element in the list using `lst[0]` and then changing it and assigning it back to `lst[0]`, so

```
lst[0] = '""' + lst[0]
```

would do it

Edit: the problem you seem to be having is that you are making an array of one element that is a string. So you have a list with the element

```
',100,"","Rock outcrop","Miscellaneous area"'
```

which is a string
what you probably want instead is to do something like

```
lst = [100,"","Rock outcrop","Miscellaneous area"]
```

and then do the insert